# Are there easy ways to measure own cognitive fitness daily?

Tags: measurement, methodology, test

I noticed I have been having quite intense ups and downs in my ability to stay focused and to solve various brain-involving tasks. It seems like these fluctuations have some time-of-day cycle (I hope it's because of my kids who have been insanely absorbing my energy recently) so I started thinking it would be nice to have an app or some other way to measure mental fitness and keep track of it, to identify patterns, and, most importantly, see if it's getting worse or better in a longer timeframe.

Do you know if there are any apps/tools/methods to keep track of own cognitive fitness (i.e., memory, ability to focus, general intelligence, etc)? I've checked App Store but all I found was rather brain puzzles, not something that I could reliably use to measure brain fitness and keep track it. On the other hand, Wikipedia shows a lot of fancy psychological tests which require a lot of time and a professional to run.

Comment: (1) I suspect that any test taken daily will have training/practice effects, (2) the scope of potential tests is far too broad for a single Q&A, and (3) also check out: [What are the standard mental health tests that are available online?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/20373/7001)